# How do I install a specific version of reiserfsprogs?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

My goal is to meet the [requirements](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/process/changes.rst) to compile the Linux kernel. I need reiserfsprogs >= 3.6.3.  I ran `sudo apt-get install reiserfsprogs`.  Then `reiserfsck -V` says 3.6.24.  I then ran `apt-cache showpkg reiserfsprogs` and it gave

> Versions:  1:3.6.24-3.1
>   (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
>   (/var/lib/dpkg/status)

My goal here is to install a specific package version so I can run the install command as below.  However, I do not understand this file version with a `:` in it.  What is that?

`sudo apt-get install reiserfsprogs=3.6.3-whateverPackageName`

Why am I getting a seemingly old version of the package?  How can I upgrade to the required minimum version?

Comment: 3.6.24 is newer than 3.6.3...

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm used to versions going up in number not down.  Can you explain this to me further please?  In other words how is `3.6.2x` newer than `3.6.3`?  Ohhh, I tottally misread it!  24 > 3 :).  Woops.  I still want to understand the remainder of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of the package encodes a number of different pieces of information:

- the epoch, before the colon (0 by default, 1 in this case);
- the upstream version number, between the colon and the hyphen (3.6.24);
- the packaging version number, after the hyphen (3.1).

Epochs are used when the upstream versioning isn't increasing, for whatever reason. Version numbers as seen by the packaging tools need to be monotonically increasing for newer releases to be considered as upgrades. In `reiserfsprogs`' case, in 2002 the version went from 3.x.1b (with an actual 'x') to 3.6.2; 3.6.2 sorts before 3.x.1b, so an epoch was added — 1:3.6.2 sorts after 3.x.1b (which is equivalent to 0:3.x.1b). [Debian policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version) has the details (and applies for Ubuntu versions too).

When you use `=` syntax with `apt`-based tools to specify the version you wish to install, you can't specify any version you like: the tools only allow you to choose between the versions available in the repositories you have configured. You can say

```
sudo apt-get install reiserfsprogs=1:3.6.3-1
```

(which is the version of 3.6.3 which appeared in the archives, as per [the changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/r/reiserfsprogs/reiserfsprogs_3.6.25-4_changelog)), but that will only work if `apt-get` can find that version in its repositories (which hasn't been possible for a long time — 3.6.3 will be fifteen years old this year).

If you really need an old version of a Debian package, you can look for them on [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org/). Archives of Ubuntu releases are available on [old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/). None of these go as far back as reiserfsprogs 3.6.3 though.

As it stands, 3.6.24 is newer than 3.6.3, and the current version of `reiserfsprogs` does satisfy your requirement.